# HTTP Downloader that supports directory index? So that I could use globbing?

Tags: wildcards, upgrade, http

Is there an `http` downloader that supports `globbing`?

i.e. I would like to fetch the latest update of a package, `abc-XXX.rpm`, but the `XXX` (version number) is unknown to me. Is it possible to do a `globbing` on directory index of the remote server?

Answer (score 1):

`lftp` sounds like what you need. (despite the name, it supports many protocols including HTTP and extracting file lists from directory indexes).

Answer (score 1):

If the server is an FTP server, [`wget`](http://www.gnu.org/software/wget/) will expand wildcards:

```
wget --no-verbose 'ftp://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/tar/*1.26*'
2012-10-02 12:02:17 URL: ftp://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/tar/*1.26* [11217] -> ".listing" [1]
2012-10-02 12:02:23 URL: ftp://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/tar/tar-1.26.cpio.gz [3421172] -> "tar-1.26.cpio.gz" [1]
2012-10-02 12:02:23 URL: ftp://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/tar/tar-1.26.cpio.gz.sig [189] -> "tar-1.26.cpio.gz.sig" [1]
2012-10-02 12:02:31 URL: ftp://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/tar/tar-1.26.shar.gz [5246246] -> "tar-1.26.shar.gz" [1]
2012-10-02 12:02:31 URL: ftp://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/tar/tar-1.26.shar.gz.sig [189] -> "tar-1.26.shar.gz.sig" [1]
2012-10-02 12:02:35 URL: ftp://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/tar/tar-1.26.tar.bz2 [2339773] -> "tar-1.26.tar.bz2" [1]
2012-10-02 12:02:35 URL: ftp://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/tar/tar-1.26.tar.bz2.sig [189] -> "tar-1.26.tar.bz2.sig" [1]
2012-10-02 12:02:41 URL: ftp://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/tar/tar-1.26.tar.gz [3435280] -> "tar-1.26.tar.gz" [1]
2012-10-02 12:02:41 URL: ftp://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/tar/tar-1.26.tar.gz.sig [189] -> "tar-1.26.tar.gz.sig" [1]
2012-10-02 12:02:45 URL: ftp://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/tar/tar-1.26.tar.xz [1783904] -> "tar-1.26.tar.xz" [1]
2012-10-02 12:02:45 URL: ftp://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/tar/tar-1.26.tar.xz.sig [189] -> "tar-1.26.tar.xz.sig" [1]
```

otherwise, as [sch suggests](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/49681/22651), use [`lftp`](http://lftp.yar.ru/):

```
lftp -c mget 'http://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/tar/*1.26*'
```